# How to iterate this dictionary of lists of lists in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the below dictionary with lists of objects.

```
args =  {'Qtag': [
                  [<Question: Question object>, <Tags: Tags object>],
                  [<Question: Question object>, <Tags: Tags object>]
                 ]
        }
```

inside my views.py

```
args=dict(Qtag=Questag)
t=loader.get.template('main.html')
c=Context(args)
```

and inside my main.html, I am trying to iterate the below way

```
{%if Qtag %}
  {% for item_list in Qtag %}
   {% for item in item_list %}
      </h4> <b> Question</b>:{{item.qid}} {{item.title}} </h4><br/>
      </h4> {{item.question}} </h4>
      <button name="tag" type="submit" value="tagname"> {{item.tagname}} </button>
   {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

When I tried the above way in my main.html, I am getting the things displayed 4 times in the screen. Here, the first list consisting of list of Question object and list of tag object corresponds to a single question and similarly for the other one, so in the screen I only want the two question and its corresponding tags to be displayed. I am not able to iterate properly to get what I need. Any thought on how to achieve this!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `args=dict(Qtag=Questag)` means in your code (since I don't know what `Questag` is). I don't know whether your tags are iterable either (I'm assuming so). Your HTML looks malformed too (e.g. I don't see an opening `h4`).

This is what I'd do to get something similar to what you're looking for. You can work on this.

```
{% if Qtag %}
   {% for question, tags in Qtag %}
     {# First put in the question header #}
     <h4>Question : {{question.qid}} {{question.title}} </h4>
     {# Then the question body #}
     <p>
     {{question.question}}
     </p>
     {# Now a tag list #}
     <ul>
     {% for tag in tags %}
       <li> 
          <button name = "tag" type="submit" value="{{tag.name}}"> 
            {{tag.name}} 
          </button>
       </li>
     {% endfor %}      
     </ul>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Your original solution is iterating over the list quadratically (you're iterating over the list once for every outer iteration) and that's why you're seeing things being printed 4 times.

Comment: Hi thanks. I got the answer. I tried with item.0.qid, i.e with item.0 for accessing the Question object and item.1 for accessing the Tags object and removed the second for loop {% for item in item_list %}.